# How to parallelize list iteration and be able to create RDDs in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've just started learning Spark and Scala.

From what I understand it's bad practice to use `collect`, because it gathers the whole data in memory and it's also bad practice to use `for`, because the code inside the block is not executed concurrently by more than one node.

Now, I have a List of numbers from 1 to 10:

`List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

and for each of these values I need to generate a `RDD` using this value.

in such cases, how can I generate the `RDD`?

By doing

```
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)).map(number => generate_rdd(number))
```

I get an error because RDD cannot be generated inside another RDD.

What is the best workaround to this problem?

Comment: why do you want to create a rdd for each value?

a rdd is defined as collection of values/instances and you would like to create just an instance as rdd for each value?

Comment: @hasan i need to use different subsets of the whole data,  I need that numeric value to filter the data at each iteration

Comment: then try .filter instead of map. it will return a rdd of the filtered(positive) values.

Comment: @hasan maybe I wasn't clear. I need to change that value 10 times, I don't think writing filter 10 times with 10 different values is clean code.

Comment: it is if the process of 10 times changing a value doesnt depend on a certain value.

for example:
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)).filter(number => number % 2 == 0).map(number => number*2).map(number => number*3)..map(number => number*4).map(<your other transformations>) as result you will get a rdd with your filtered and processed values. if this does not help, please explain what concretely you plan to do

Comment: @hasan please read my question, it's not just matter of filtering that list, but iterating over it in a parallel way and still being able to generate RDD inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `generate_rdd` defined like `def generate_rdd(n: Int): RDD[Something]` what you need is `flatMap` instead of `map`.

```
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)).flatMap(number => generate_rdd(number))
```

This will give a RDD that is a concatenation of all RDDs that are created for numbers from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of RDDs that you would like to create would be lower and hence that parallelization itself need not be accomplished by RDD, we can use Scala's parallel collections instead. For example, I tried to count the number of lines in about 40 HDFS files simultaneously using the following piece of code [Ignore the setting of delimiter. For newline delimited texts, this could have well been replaced by `sc.textFile`]:

```
val conf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "~^~")
val parSeq = List("path of file1.xsv","path of file2.xsv",...).par
parSeq.map(x => {
  val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(x, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
  println(rdd.count())
})
```

Here is part of the output in Spark UI. As seen, most of the RDD count operations started at the same time.

[image: Spark UI]